Identify movie with passengers happily exiting airliner (but actually entering heaven)
Only caught like 10-15 minutes of this movie shown on "regular TV." Can't even recall when I saw it, not going to guess...
Sequence I saw involved large group of passengers getting off a commercial airliner; all very happy - laughing, smiling, etc - POV is of an uninvolved (?) on-looker (seems like on-looker was male, but, again - not sure)
This person comes to realization/knowledge this is no ordinary, everyday airport scene. In reality, the plane has crashed killing all onboard, and what onlooker is seeing is the entire group, as a whole, passing from "this earth" and entering "heaven." 

They're not getting off, they are boarding, but there's a scene like it in 1978's "Heaven Can Wait"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35fEjN5m4ds

Might be "Millennium", a 1989 scifi b-movie about crashing airliners whose passengers are, in fact, 

being taken forward in time and replaced with lookalike corpses.

I don't remember it specifically being about "heaven", but there is a strong afterlife-y component to the passengers' experience, IIRC.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097883/

There wasn't a scene like this in Millennium. It's more likely a Left Behind-style movie.

@aryxus The whole "walk toward the light" bit was pretty reminiscent, IMO, and I thought the present-day investigator witnesses one such occurrence. But, it's been awhile...

Actually, I could see where the OP might have gotten that from Millennium. My apologies.

This sounds like Millennium (1989).  People are exiting an airplane and being told to "move along - walk toward the light - remain calm," as they walk toward the light.
"An NTSB investigator seeking the cause of an airline disaster meets a warrior woman from 1000 years in the future. She replaces the people from airplanes before they crash with corpses with the same features."  IMDB-Link to the movie.

There is also the additional light that you might be thinking of.  

